# R - Find index of element from one dataframe and place in another

Tags: r, dataframe

Folks, I have 2 data frames as follows.

**df1**  Sorted in reverse order showing the number of times an activity has taken place.
Activity    # of Occurrences
Walking     38
Jogging     26
Running 12

**df2**  Shows the calories burned doing the activity, again sorted in reverse order of Calories Burned.
Activity    Calories Burned
Running     38
Walking     27
Jogging    12

I would like to add a second column on df2, showing the row index of the Activity from df1. So for example, Running is in Row 3 df1 (row-wise) but it's in Row 1 in df2. Hence is there a way for me to add a second column showing the row indices from df1 as below ?

**df2 updated**: (or df3)
Activity    Calories Burned     Occurrence Index
Running     38                  3
Walking     27                  1
Jogging     12                  2

All the data comes from one underlying table df0, where each incidence of Activity is recorded as a separate row. I summarise it into df1 & df2 but unsure how to go about the last step. Thanks !

Comment: Dale, akrun, Thanks for your answers; they are both excellent ! akrun I accepted yours based upon being 1 line vs. 2. I have upvoted both. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to create the new column

```
df1$OccurrenceIndex <-  match(df2$Activity, df1$Activity)
df1
#  Activity NoOfOccurrences OccurrenceIndex
#1  Walking              38               3
#2  Jogging              26               1
#3  Running              12               2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the indexes in df1 to a new colum "Index". Then, you can lookup the values by Activity name using the `merge()` function.

```
df1$df1_Index <- as.numeric(row.names(df1))
df2 <- merge(df2,df1[c("Activity","df1_Index")],by="Activity")
```